# Curry in Haskell

Tags: haskell

as you know the foldl function is defined as :

```
  foldl :: (a -> b -> a ) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

I want to rewrite the function as an uncurrified function

I tried this one:

```
   foldl :: ( (a-> b-> a) , a , [b] ) -> a
```

Is that correct? Maybe it is not important to uncurry but I am gonna write an exam and I am pretty sure this will be one of the tasks to do.

Thanks in anticipation !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that sure is an uncurried form of `foldl`. However, there a more levels on which you can do this – what I'd can the "fully uncurried form" would be

```
foldl'' :: ( ((a,b) -> a), a, [b] ) -> a
```

where not just the function itself but also its function argument is uncurried. OTOH, just calling `uncurry` on the function would yield merely

```
foldl''' :: ( (a->b->a), a ) -> [b] -> a
```

which might thus also be called "uncurried `foldl`", though it would certainly not be the desired interpretation in an exam.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help. I think it'd be enough using "foldl'' " in our case. Thank you.